# Using mysqli query to display second query while still displaying first query

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to have two separate queries. The first query I would like to display a bunch of numbers in descending order in a table (pretty simple to do). Then what I would like to do is a second query which for each of those matching numbers I would like to display the corresponding data. The reason I want to do it separately instead of just combing it all into one query is so that I can display all of the results of the first query whether it has data or not. IE:
1 - (blank)
2 - I have data
3 - I also have data
4 - (blank)
5 - I have more data

So far the code I am using is:

```
// Perform number query
$number_query = mysqli_query($con,$num_query);
while($numbers = mysqli_fetch_array($number_query)) {

// Do data query
$data_query = mysqli_query($con,$d_query);
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($data_query)) {
    if ($numbers['number'] == $data['number']) {
        echo $numbers['number'];
        echo $data['content'];
        echo '<br>';
        }
    else {
        echo $numbers['number'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
    }

}
```

I dont think I'm taking the right approach but it does seem that I am getting partially the right results as it is displaying the data next to the numbers with content. The problem is that for each piece of data in the database the $numbers['number'] is being replicated. So if $data['content'] has 5 database entries then each entry of the $numbers['number'] is being replicated 5 times.

-------Edit-----

Ok I realized why my question wasnt making sense (maybe). I'm going to use an example of these tables:

Table 1

### unique_id | number | identifier | etc

Database Table 1 might be updated once a month, and all the numbers and identifiers *must* be visible on the page at all times. The query needs to be kept separate because it is used multiple times (more then 10) on other pages so I've included it outside of the page in a header file.

Table 2

### unique_id | number | description | etc.

Database Table 2 needs to be referenced via the number columns, this content is changing on an interval of about every 10-15 minutes, now Table 1 might only have 50 rows of data while Table 2 probably has close to a 100+ new rows a day. The query is embedded on the page because it will be the only page that actually uses this specific query.

The idea with the layout is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Number & Identifier</td>  (taken from Table 1)
<td>Description</td> (content from table 2)
<td>(more content from table 2)</td>
etc
```

So looking back at the top with my question is the problem is that for every description and other content that is being displayed on the page with the corresponding number and identifier information, all the number and identifiers without descriptions or content are being replicated the same amount of times as there are entries with descriptions and content.

If I remove the else conditional statement then the issue becomes that the blank entries do not display at all, which doesnt meet my requirements. The reason that these blank entries need to be in there is that this page can be printed off, so people not using computers can fill out the blank fields with pen/pencil and it can be manually entered in after the fact.

Comment: Can you give us a database layout or maybe the queries? I don't quite understand what u are trying to accomplish

Comment: Basically I have two massive databases. I have a layout with a five column table. The first table cell of every row has a name and number in it which is generated from the database. These are identifier names and ID numbers and all come from one database. The info from the 1st table needs to be displayed 100% of the time. The second query of the database on the second db table which contains a massive amount of relevant information to that id info and number from the first table is to be pulled and displayed in the other four columns. Does that make more sense? I just gave simple code.

Comment: Post you query, maybe all you need is a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do understand your question now, but i still think that the solution using join as i posted earlier is your best bet.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26854/2

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, I used the query you suggested and the following code: 
$db_query = mysqli_query($con,$db_data_query);
 while($db_res = mysqli_fetch_array($db_query)) {
  echo $db_res['number'];
  echo '<br>';
 }

Unfortunately this only shows the 3 numbers with content and ignores all the blank numbers of the second mysql table.

Comment: I need to see the actual query please.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working now playing with left and right joins